# Where are the connection files for IIS Manager for Remote Administration?

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have [IIS Manager for Remote Administration](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177) installed on one PC and now I have a new PC and want to move the connections I setup on my old PC. But I don't know where are the connection files are saved. I tried to look into my Profile but don't have a clue on where they are.

I have the 32bit on the old PC and 64bit on the new PC. I also wonder if the connection files can be shared among them at all?

Answer (score 2):

I found the file. It's located at

```
c:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WebManagement\7.0.0.0\InetMgr.preferences
```

then you can just create the necessary folders and copy the file from old PC to new.